# 'Export-PowerBIReport' cmdlet gives the BadRequest error

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am using the 'Export-PowerBIReport' cmdlet from 'MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt' powershell module.

Some workspaces work fine, I can loop the workspace reports and export all reports. Other workspaces give me an error message. In both workspaces I have Admin role. Why am I getting an error message "BadRequest (400)"?

Script: Export Report (fail)

```
PS > 

$wsRname = 'MyReport_Test'
$wsName = 'Workspace #1'
$Fileout = 'C:\OneDrive\MyFolder\$wsName\_EXPORT'
$wsId = 'abaf4ecc-56c0-417d-8014-7059ba005f71'
$wsRid = '65b9b2d8-a803-4728-a87c-1652eba12d5b'

Export-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $wsId -Id $wsRid -OutFile "$Fileout\$wsRname.pbix" -Verbose

OUTPUT >

VERBOSE: Request Uri: https://api.powerbigov.us/v1.0/myorg/groups/abaf4ecc-56c0-417d-8014-7059ba005f71/reports/65b9b2d8-a803-4728-a87c-1652eba12d5b/Export
VERBOSE: Status Code: BadRequest (400)
```

Script: Export Report (succeed)

```
PS > 

$wsRname = 'MyReport_Test'
$wsName = 'Workspace #1'
$Fileout = 'C:\OneDrive\MyFolder\$wsName\_EXPORT'
$wsId = '11933af7-44c4-4ef1-a9d8-f3e19f8077c8'
$wsRid = '215ad91a-2ef9-4584-bfdc-e5a2ffcf760e'

Export-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $wsId -Id $wsRid -OutFile "$Fileout\$wsRname.pbix" -Verbose

OUTPUT >

 VERBOSE: OutFile 'C:\Users\VHAFAVLoftoB\OneDrive - Department of Veterans Affairs\MyOneDrive\PBI\Workspaces\PBIX Export\The Workspace\_EXPORT\MyReport_Test.pbix' created
 VERBOSE: Request Uri: https://api.powerbigov.us/v1.0/myorg/groups/11933af7-44c4-4ef1-a9d8-f3e19f8077c8/reports/215ad91a-2ef9-4584-bfdc-e5a2ffcf760e/Export
 VERBOSE: Status Code: OK (200)
```

Script: List workspace reports

> The 'Get-PowerBIReport' cmdlet return the expected objects. But 'Export-PowerBIReport' cmdlet gives the BadRequest error.

```
PS > 

Get-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId abaf4ecc-56c0-417d-8014-7059ba005f71 | select Id, Name, DatasetId  | ft -auto 

OUTPUT > 

Id                                   Name                        DatasetId                           
--                                   ----                        ---------                           
c44d88d1-d875-46ca-94f7-559d87e7583e Report Usage Metrics Report 3faf34d2-da32-4ce4-8b1c-809226148cda
65b9b2d8-a803-4728-a87c-1652eba12d5b HCDW Dashboard              c88c5137-92d7-4100-848f-072adb402107
d62ac462-b433-48ee-a085-109ddacb09c3 AVD - Dev - NoEncr          8bd3f86e-8129-4653-a3e7-dacbadc08e74
```

Answer (score 0):

If a dataset is stored as Large dataset, downloading as a .pbix file will fail. You must turn off this setting to download the file. Then, if needed, you can turn it back on.

PBI Settings Page

- 'Storage format' can be change/configured for the individual datasets.
- 'Default storage format' setting in the PBI Workspace.
- 'Dataset size can be viewed from the workspace settings, using the elipse (...) in the top right corner.

REFERENCE

[Large datasets in Power BI Premium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-large-models#enable-large-models)

[How to Configure Large Dataset Format in Power BI? | PL-300 Tutorial Episode 15 | Power BI - BI Consulting Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9LL1itqbAU)